# Rails 3 ActiveRecord chaining

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm new to Rails and I'm not sure why my chaining isn't working.

Working

```
my_model.select('name').where('status_id = 6').all
```

Not Working

```
my_model.select('name').where('status_id = 6').order('name')
```

Why does chaining the `order` after the `where` not execute the query?  I've tried adding the `.all` after the `.order` but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Is the code giving you an error or just returning an empty array?

Comment: I'm getting 'NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!  You might have expected an instance of Array.  The error occurred while evaluating nil)

Comment: Can you watch your server output window, or "tail -f log/*" ? Let us know what the SQL output is, if you're not getting an error.

Comment: That would imply that your "where" query is returning nil...

Comment: But when i leave off the order it get results back

Comment: Then unless I'm wrong it's saying your select().where() query is returning a nil object?

Comment: Did you try to place order before where?

Comment: the problem is inside your __VIEW__ for this action. show your view

Comment: @fl00r - I don't believe it's in my view because when i execute the query without the 'order' clause in the rails console it works / then when i add the 'order' clause I get: NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.<<
 from /home/mspangler/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.1/lib/arel/visitors/sql_server.rb:34:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectStatement'

Comment: Can we know when will it be released to rubygems.org?

Comment: Please post your solution as the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a known bug in the jdbc adapter: http://kenai.com/jira/browse/ACTIVERECORD_JDBC-154

If you make these changes it will fix it: https://github.com/ystael/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/commit/8815d2fe133afb6774ebe12cc27c3a977dbf7ad2