# Rails3: How to manage tainted gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, bundler, activerecord-jdbc

I'm a n00b in Rails and in Rails 3. I had to patch `activerecord-jdbc-adapter` source locally because of a bug. See [Rails 3 ActiveRecord chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357458/rails-3-activerecord-chaining) for details. I modified locally `lib/arel/visitors/sql_server.rb` as described by the page https://github.com/ystael/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/commit/8815d2fe133afb6774ebe12cc27c3a977dbf7ad2.

I would like to manage these changes until the problem is solved centrally with a special attention on smooth deployment. What commands should I run? Which path should I apply the patch on? Which things should I add to my SVN repo? How will I deploy then?

Here is my Gemfile, maybe counts:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre'
gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter'
gem 'activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add git repository to you gem command.

```
gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter', :git => 'git://github.com/..REPOSITORY...git'
```